# When does Moiraine say 'she asked questions'?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

In *The Eye of the World*, the first novel in *The Wheel of Time* saga:

> [Moiraine] smiled drily at his surprise, "I told you I asked questions."

I don't recall reading that she has said that. Where and when in the novel does she say this?

Comment: Seeing as WoT appears to be your favorite series, I do not understand why you put 'novel' and 'saga' in scare quotes. Is it meant to indicate something? Anyway, I am completely flummoxed as to why Moiraine says this. I went back through my electronic copy of this book, looking at all her lines to figure out where she indicated either (a) general inquisitiveness or (b) having asked questions around the village. Absolutely no luck. The closest I can find is she asked someone in particular to 'answer a few of her questions'.

Comment: Quotes around 'novel' and 'saga' don't make sense in this context, so don't add them back.

Comment: What are you quoting, if not a quote from the book?

Answer (score 3):

To be frank, I cannot think of anything she said up to that point that would convey the impression that she is generally inquisitive, or that she asked a lot of questions during her stay, both of which would be reasonably valid interpretations of the phrase "I ask questions" in context. I read basically all the scenes where she appears up to that point, and here are the few candidates I found:

> Her smile did fade then, slowly, as if something had been recalled to
> her. For a moment she merely looked at him. “I am a student of
> history,” she said at last, “a collector of old stories. This place
> you call the Two Rivers has always interested me. Sometimes I study
> the stories of what happened here long ago, here and at other places.”

In this quote, she indicates a certain curiosity with regard to Two Rivers, which is however framed as academic, and is not connected  with asking questions in particular. Also, she is talking about an interest in ancient history, specifically, which does not seem particularly related to knowing the ages of its residents in the present day.

It could also be a reference to this:

> “Perhaps now,” Moiraine said quietly, “you will answer a few of my
> questions. I have answered yours freely enough.”

However, this quote does not include a statement of a proclivity for asking questions in general, and it certainly does not set up her knowing their ages.

Short of authorial error, which seems like the most probable explanation, it is not impossible that Moiraine said this "offscreen", so to speak. and that this represents the first time that the reader is meant to be informed of it. It is a bit more subtle and experimental than I would expect from Robert Jordan, but it is not at all out of the question.